# Can't make scheduled event

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've read about AlarmManager and decided to make a simple app, which would send me a notification at particular time but i can't understand what is wrong. Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);
}}
```

And MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
private NotificationManager mManager;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .build();

    mManager.notify(1, notification);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.hfad.alarmmanager.AlarmReciever"/>
</application>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
```

must be

```
public class AlarmReciever extends WakefullBroadcastReceiver
```

and than call in `onReceive`

```
Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
startWakefulService(service1);
```

Comment: With pleasure .